# Align text with heading

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

Is there an easy way to align the text block with a section title? 
It should look like this:

```
1      Introduction
       This is an example text.

1.1    Section
       This text should also be intended.

1.1.1  Subsection
       \ldots :)
```

PS: I am using the `scrreprt` documentclass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redefine `\chapterformat` and `\@seccntformat` appropriately; change the length `\mylen` according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{2cm}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
  \llap{\protect\makebox[\mylen][l]{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter\autodot\hfill}}%
}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\llap{\protect\makebox[\mylen][l]{\csname the#1\endcsname\autodot\hfill}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[4]
\section{Text Section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Text Subsection}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that i need this for sections, too. There seems to be no `\sectionformat` to set.

Comment: @klingt.net Just sections or also subsections, subsubsections?

Comment: Even sub- and subsubsections, but they should not be intended more than the chapter.

Comment: @klingt.net please see my updated answer.